# Adding values from different rows to VBA collection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping someone with more VBA knowledge than me can teach me how to adjust my code to get the outcome I'm looking for. Let me start with the data I'll be using:

[image: Data]

| PO Number | Vendor Item # | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MO-0021244 | NFLPACK8D | 1 |
| MO-0021244 | NFLPACK9D | 1 |
| MO-008512 | NFLPACK8M | 1 |
| MO-965403 | NFLPACK9 | 1 |
| MO-780066 | SOCLAM1 | 1 |

And current code (Class Module):

```
Public Key As String
Public SKU1 As String
Public Quantity1 As Long
Public SKU2 As String
Public Quantity2 As Long
Public SKU3 As String
Public Quantity3 As Long
Public SKU4 As String
Public Quantity4 As Long
Public SKU5 As String
Public Quantity5 As Long
Public ItemList As Collection
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    SKU1 = 0
    Quantity1 = 0
    SKU2 = 0
    Quantity2 = 0
    SKU3 = 0
    Quantity3 = 0
    SKU4 = 0
    Quantity4 = 0
    SKU5 = 0
    Quantity5 = 0
    Set ItemList = New Collection
End Sub
```

(Module)

```
Public Sub POClass()

Dim col As Collection
Dim dataItems As cItems
Dim itemKey As String
Dim item1 As String
Dim item2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set col = New Collection

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lastRow
    itemKey = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "A").Value2)
    item1 = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "M").Value2)
    item2 = CLng(ws.Cells(r, "N").Value2)

    'Check if key already exists
    Set dataItems = Nothing: On Error Resume Next
    Set dataItems = col(itemKey): On Error GoTo 0

    'If key doesn't exist, create a new class object
    If dataItems Is Nothing Then
        Set dataItems = New cItems
        dataItems.Key = itemKey
        col.Add dataItems, itemKey
    End If

    'Add cell values to the class object
    With dataItems
        .SKU = item1
        .Quantity = item2
        .ItemList.Add item1
        .ItemList.Add item2
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Essentially, I'm trying to have the macro go through each row and do the following:

1. Add PO Number to the collection
2. Add each Vendor Item# and Qty to the corresponding PO Number
3. Store each Vendor Item# and Qty in SKU1-5 and Quantity 1-5

Each PO might have as little as 1 item or up to 5. Am I doing this correctly or is there a better way? I can't figure out how to get SKUs/Quantities added to the same PO number if there are multiple for one PO.

So the expected output would be:

Key: MO-0021244
SKU1: NFLPACK8D
Quantity1: 1
SKU2: NFLPACK9D
Quantity2: 1

Key: MO-008512
SKU1: NFLPACK8M
Quantity1: 1

Key: MO-965403
SKU1: NFLPACK9
Quantity1: 1

Key: MO-780066
SKU1: SOCLAM1
Quantity1: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary instead of a collection to make it easier to store the SKU and quantities together and this approach scales better when you have a lot of possible values. You completely avoid having to define variables with an index (Quantity1, Quantity2, Quantity3, etc.).

Your class module would then be:

```vb
Public Key As String
Public ItemList As Dictionary 'Requires Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library (Tools > References... > Add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" > Press OK)
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set ItemList = New Dictionary
End Sub
```

Which would give you this data structure (class diagram):

[image]

Then, in your code module, you'd replace :

```vb
    'Add cell values to the class object
    With dataItems
        .sku = item1
        .Quantity = item2
        .ItemList.Add item1
        .ItemList.Add item2
    End With
```

with

```vb
    'Add cell values to the class object
    dataItems.ItemList.Add item1, item2
```

Then you can loop over the values and return the output you mentioned in your quesiton like this :

```vb
Dim cItem As cItems
For Each cItem In col
    
    Dim qtyDetails As String
    qtyDetails = vbNullString

    Dim sku As Variant
    For Each sku In cItem.ItemList.Keys
        qtyDetails = qtyDetails & " SKU: " & sku & " Quantity: " & cItem.ItemList(sku)
    Next sku

    Debug.Print "Key: " & cItem.Key & " " & qtyDetails

Next
```

Also note that you could avoid using a class and use a nested dictionary instead.

Comment: So in this scenario, would each unique PO Number be a unique key in the dictionary with potentially multiple SKUs/quantities? Or will there be (2) MO-0021244 entries with a SKU and quantity for each like in the table you made?

Comment: @EliGreenberg - No, in this scenario, each PO Number is the unique key of the `cItems` class object and that class object includes a list named `itemList` that contains an idenfinite number of Key-Value pairs for SKU and Quantity. See edit for a visual reprensentation.

Comment: What if I wanted to add more properties to each PO number? Would they have to be in key/value pairs? In the end I'm hoping to have several properties for each PO number, to include SKU and quantity.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like up to 5 SKU/quantity pairs along with several "unpaired" properties such as shipping address and ZIP code per unique PO number key.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment : "that class object includes a [dictionary] named... `itemList` ..."

Comment: @EliGreenberg - That's not a problem. If you need to add more values that are uniquely associated to a PO Number, you can simply add them as members of you `cItems` class.

Comment: Dictionaries are proving to be very confusing for me compared to collections (which are also confusing haha). I have a sanitized data file. Could I send it you somehow along with the data structure I'm hoping to achieve and you provide some tips?

Comment: Let's discuss it in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254168/discussion-between-eligreenberg-and-decimalturn)